# inject dependecy to custom filter angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I want to inject $http on my custom filter to use it on my view:

```
angular.module('demo').filter('quesByID',['$http', function() {
var input="";
    return function(input) {
        $http.get("http://localhost:3003/api/quiz/"+input).then(function(reponse){
             input=reponse.data;
        });
            return input;

    }

}]);
```

I got error that $http is not defined

```
angular.js:13920 ReferenceError: $http is not defined
    at getQuestionById.js:4
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14817), <anonymous>:4:198)
    at regularInterceptedExpression (angular.js:16043)
    at expressionInputWatch (angular.js:15948)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17515)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17790)
    at done (angular.js:11831)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:12033)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:11966)
```

Where should I inject the "$http" dependecy ?

Comment: you need to actually supply `$http` as an argument to the function;  i.e. `function($http) {`

Comment: why are you using a filter for this?

Comment: You're misusing a filter. Use a service instead. Doing this in controller (like the answer suggests) is a quick fix but can hardly be called the best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You injected the `dependency` but not used as a `argument` in function

Don't use filter for this, you can write your code in controller

```
angular.module('demo').controller('controller',['$http', function($http) {
    $scope.data;
    $scope.getData = function(input) {
        $http.get("http://localhost:3003/api/quiz/"+input).then(function(reponse){
             $scope.data = reponse.data;
        });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: `$http` is **asynchronous** This simply will not work

Comment: I have fixed the main issue of user, not all. But now i updated all the things

Comment: Still won't work ... how would you  use a promise returned from a filter? Also consider how many times this request would get made when using such a filter in the view. Whole thing doesn't make sense

Comment: This is not a actual problem of @Nour Jadlaoui, the main problem is dependency injection

Comment: But it's your problem now too since you provided an answer that can't work. You can't see it due to less than 10k rep but others have already deleted the same answer for the same reason

Comment: i can understand filter for this type of functionality will not work. he directly call a function from controller for this.

Comment: why are you telling me that? Your answer will not do what OP is expecting....period!. It is useless code using the wrong tool for the job

Comment: @Gaurav i possted the same answer and deleted :)